# How to map a boolean database value to Java Enumeration

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, enums, boolean, entity

For Strings this is easy using attribute Converter. How to find a pattern for boolean?

I have an enum which is just

```
public enum InsuranceStatus
{
   Active, Inactive
}
```

and I would like to find the enum value of a boolean.

Comment: Write an attribute converter for `AttributeConverter<InsuranceStatus ,Boolean>`

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot change the enum :

```
public class InsuranceStatusConverter implements AttributeConverter<InsuranceStatus, Boolean> {

    @Override
    public Boolean convertToDatabaseColumn(InsuranceStatus status) {
        return status == InsuranceStatus.Active ? true : false
    }

    @Override
    public InsuranceStatus convertToEntityAttribute(Boolean status) {
        return status == true ? InsuranceStatus.Active : InsuranceStatus.Inactive ;          
    }
}
```

If you can change the enum, move the logic here as much as possible because the  model (the enum) is reusable in many other contexts while the converter is dedicated to a single case :

```
 enum InsuranceStatus { 
   ACTIVE(true), INACTIVE(false);
   private boolean status;  
  
    public static InsuranceStatus valueOf(Boolean status){
        // Or throw an exception instead of returning null if more appropriate      
       if (status == null) { return null;}
       return status == true ? InsuranceStatus.ACTIVE: InsuranceStatus.INACTIVE;          

    }    
    private InsuranceStatus (boolean status) {  
         this.status = status;  
    }  
    public boolean getStatus(){
        return status;
    }      
} 

public class InsuranceStatusConverter implements AttributeConverter<InsuranceStatus, Boolean> {

    @Override
    public Boolean convertToDatabaseColumn(InsuranceStatus status) {
        return status.getStatus();
    }

    @Override
    public InsuranceStatus convertToEntityAttribute(Boolean status) {
       return InsuranceStatus.valueOf(status);                     
    }
}
```

At last update your entity to use that converter :

```
@Convert(converter = InsuranceStatusConverter.class)
private InsuranceStatus status;
```

Comment: @Rono Indeed that is a typo. Don't hesitate to edit : )